# Word request for a in-game page

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice

So I'm playing a video game,the gameplay is similar to that of street fighter where I just control one fighter and try to defeat the opponents. When the fight is over, whether I won or not, a rectangular shaped pop-up 'chart' will come up showing a summary of it covering the hits delivered and received and also the rewards.

So here's my first question: what are the pop-up 'charts' called or is there an expression?

And heading to the next question, there is recently a new 'chart' of a different style which includes more details and due to the complexity of explaining it is shown in the attached picture, so the second question is: what word should I use to refer to this upgraded chart?

For convenience of understanding pictures of both 'charts' are attached below.

[image: original]

[image: detailed]

Comment: How are you intending to use these terms? Are you describing these pages to people in the video games industry, or to gamers or to your friends? Different groups are likely to use different terms.

Comment: The first picture says *Rewards*, and that's what it shows. The next is *Fight Details*, *Fight Scores*,  *Fight Stats*?

Comment: @KillingTime Thanks for your reply, I was actually describing it to my friends who don't play this game when I came up with the first question cause' in the conversation I termed it a 'pop-up chart that shows the game result' and that seems cumbersome and also inaccurate with regard to the word 'chart' so I wonder if there's a replacement, for the second question I'm wondering since there are some modifications if there should be another word for it

Comment: In gaming, it would be called _endgame stats_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term Pop-up is fine and quite accurate as far as it goes. In the programming realm the term for this is a *Modal* window. That is a window that you cannot ignore or dismiss by clicking the window behind or elsewhere. It takes and holds the program's focus until a button on the modal form, like an 'OK' or 'Cancel' button (not present in this case) is clicked or some external action takes place such as a restart. Your first example shows "Tap anywhere to continue" as the way out of the modal window.

In your case a detailed description would be the *modal rewards* window and the *modal details* window respectively.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Elliot, this is exactly the answer I want.